# Can I use the OptiX AI-Accelerated Denoiser for rendering animations?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, animation, denoise

Can I use the OptiX AI-Accelerated Denoiser for rendering? I can only find it for viewport denoising, not for denoising a render. How do I enable the OptiX AI-Accelerated Denoiser for rendering, and can I use it for rendering character animations?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep. Click on the layers tab and its down at the bottom

[image]